# How can I submit a transaction created in --do-not-relay mode?

Tags: cold-storage

I've created a transaction in wallet started with `--do-not-relay` switch. It landed in `raw_monero_tx` file.

How can I push it to the network using wallet software? I know about online pushers but want to do it locally.

`submit_transfer` looks for `signed_monero_tx` and requires the file to have magic prefix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content of `raw_monero_tx` is a raw byte array of a complete tx that is meant to be passed to the daemon RPC `/sendrawtransaction`. Here's an example on testnet (you need to have your testnet daemon running by doing `monerod --testnet`):

```
~$ cat raw_monero_tx 
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

~$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:28081/sendrawtransaction -d '{"do_not_relay": false, "tx_as_hex":"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"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
{
  "double_spend": false,
  "fee_too_low": false,
  "invalid_input": false,
  "invalid_output": false,
  "low_mixin": false,
  "not_rct": false,
  "not_relayed": false,
  "overspend": false,
  "reason": "",
  "status": "OK",
  "too_big": false
}
```

Note that you need to set `do_not_relay` to `false` in order to make the daemon relay the transaction.

Comment: Thanks. It works but... how can I relay it via RPC?

Comment: You can't, AFAIK.

Comment: I was wrong, the latest version of the RPC has the `do_not_relay` parameter, so you can set it to `false` to make the daemon relay the tx. Updated my post as such.

Comment: Yea, found it out too. Already posted a PR with update for the docs and created a ticket questioning the weird default behavior. Great thanks for your help!